# Pluginf for Different header image on every pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need wordpress plugin for this kind of header image http://www.slb.com/services/drilling.aspx like in this web site. And this image will not be slider but it's static image on perticular page and category and also different image for all categories and pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest & best way is create a custom field named `banner` &  in your `header.php` place below code.

```
<div class="banner">
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true)) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<div>
```

But as you want plugin to do this, have a look at plugin named [**Dynamic Header**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-headers/screenshots/).

Comment: using this plugin header image exactly not in place as shown in above link , and i need exact location for the header image.

Comment: But i don't understand how to use this code and how give image URL to this code so header image can display ..

Comment: You need to create a custom field. Check this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields it will show you  how it works.

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.